# Change Regional Setting in site collection using Office 365?

Tags: office-365, regional-settings

Currently, we have Office 365 tenant which currently have a default regional setting. What we want to achieve is to change the default regional setting in Office 365 for the whole Tenant.

Please advise how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change using

1. Site Settings (Gear Icon) from the top bar
2. Then click on "Regional Settings" under "Site Administration"
3. Change "Time Zone"
4. Click Ok

Comment: Thank you. would this also apply if the tenant host in cloud?. sorry i miss this part.

Comment: Yes. The change will only get applied to that site.

Comment: Would this apply to whole office365 tenant?

Comment: Not for the whole. But specific to the site you are changing the setting. You can test this by creating multiple sites and changing it in one place.

Comment: Thanks. I have modified the question for changing the regional setting for the whole tenant.